# if timestamp range is within timestamp range

Tags: php, math, timestamp

I have an array of timestamps and duration and an array of occupied timestamps.
I now need to check if these timestamps collide.

Basically $start[] cannot be within any of the $occupied[] timestamps

```
$start[0] = 1486987200; // 12:00
$duration[0] = 3600;

$start[1] = 1487008800; // 18:00
$duration[1] = 7200;

$occupied[0] = 1486989000; // 12:30
$ocDuration[0] = 3600;

$occupied[1] = 1487019600; // 21:00
$ocDuration[1] = 7200;
```

From the above `$start[0]` is not possible because `$occupied[0]` is within its range of 1 hour (3600 seconds), but `$start[1]` IS possible because it starts at 18:00, and ends 2 hours later.

[image]

Another situation could be when `$occupied[0]` overlaps both `$start[]`:

[image]

So the question is, how can i do such a check ?

Comment: Loved the description and demonstration

Comment: For this kind of thing an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) is an excellent data structure. I don't know if there are any PHP implementations of one; but I've successfully built similar stuff on Python libraries like [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) one.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will look into the interval tree. Seems like this could be good to have in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkTimeSlot($occupied, $occDuration, $checkStart, $checkDuration)
{
    $isValid = true;
    foreach($occupied as $key => $occStartTime)
    {
        $occEndTime = $occStartTime + $occDuration;
        if($checkStart > $occStartTime || $checkStart < $occEnd || $occEndTime > $occStartTime || $occEndTime < $occEndTime)
        {
            $isValid = false;
        }
    }

    return $isValid;
}


$isValid = [];
foreach ($start as $key => $checkStart)
{
    $isValid[$key] = checkTimeSlot($checkStart, $duration[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will use $start and $duration as non-array variables, you can use this one below. Otherwise, just write a double for-loop.

```
$start[0] = 1486987200; // 12:00
$duration[0] = 3600;

$start[1] = 1487008800; // 18:00
$duration[1] = 7200;

$occupied[0] = 1486989000; // 12:30
$ocDuration[0] = 3600;

$occupied[1] = 1487019600; // 21:00
$ocDuration[1] = 7200;

$occupied[2] = 1486989000; // 12:30
$ocDuration[2] = 23400;

function checkOccupancy($start, $duration, $occupied, $ocDuration){
    $ocLength = count($occupied);
    for($i = 0; $i <= $ocLength; $i++){
        $ocEnd = $occupied[$i] + $ocDuration[$i];
        $end = $start + $duration;
        if(($start > $occupied[$i] && $start < $ocEnd) || ($end > $occupied[$i] && $end < $ocEnd) ){
            return "Not Possible";
        }
    }
    return "Possible";
}

echo checkOccupancy($start[0], $duration[0], $occupied, $ocDuration);
echo checkOccupancy($start[1], $duration[1], $occupied, $ocDuration);
```